# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference OTP SMS Listener Error

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to fetch the OTP(One time Password) From SMS received automatically. I have used this code in 3 projects and I have never faced this error before and when I am printing the variable then I am getting a value in it. Then how can msgBody is throwing error for empty object

```
        if (bundle != null) {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                }
                if (OTPFragment.onReciveSMS != null) {
                    msgBody = msgBody.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
                    msgBody = msgBody.replace(".", "");
                    OTPFragment.onReciveSMS.setOnReciveSMS("sms", msgBody.trim());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("SMS Listener Exception",e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: check msgBody value, most probably msgBody will be null

Comment: I have tried it but I am getting a value in it. So it is not null